# How to trigger eclipse plugin update programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a requirement that I need to trigger eclipse plugin update through code.Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to install/update a specific plug-in, use the [p2 operations API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_api_overview.htm) ([Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/equinox/p2/operations/package-summary.html)). Otherwise, if you want to execute the global system update command, execute the command 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.update' programmatically, as described in [this blog post](http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/09/snippet-of-the-day-execute-eclipse-command-programmatically/).

Comment: Ujhelyi Could you please provide sample code snippet indicating utilization of p2 operations API?

Comment: I have edited the answer to contain a link for the p2 operations api instead of the javadoc - originally I wanted to share this link, and it also contains at least some snippets. In truth I have never directly programmed the p2 operations API, but know it is used for that reason.